# How do I use quantilevalues as priors in R?

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm working with a project to prove that some expert judgements are false.

I'm thinking bayesian-methods could be helpful to work with, but I don't have much knowledge about this topic. I know theoretically how it works with bayes theorem etc.

I have data on continuous level following a normal distribution, and quantiles value as priors, lets say:

```
    For example:
    data <- c(0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.06, 0.04)
    quantile1 <- list(p=0.5, x=0.04774)
    quantile2 <- list(p=0.1, x=0.02549306)
    quantile3 <- list(p=0.9, x=0.4)
```

Is it possible to use these quantile values as priors? Which packages etc could I use? How do I find my posterior distribution with this information?

Comment: Hi! This is not a programming, but a stochastics or statistics question, and hence off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that this is not a forum for your favourite programming language, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related problems. Thus, please [edit] the question to contain the tag of the language you're actually using.

Comment: I have the same question, found this discussion in a Python context, on the hunt for an R approach.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56371/Finding-Probability-Distribution-Parameters-from-P